Installed Lazy -- which NeoVim plugin is converting $() to backticks? and how to remove it?
I just installed Lazy via the instructions here: https://www.lazyvim.org/installation
That is, I just did this, and then started nvim:
git clone https://github.com/LazyVim/starter ~/.config/nvim

Clearly this LazyVim "starter" install includes a number of plugins.  Everything looks nice, but something annoying is in the plugins.  When I opened a bash script in nvim, made an unrelated minor change, and then saved the file, I noticed that nvim (or one of its plugins) automatically replaced a bash
$(<command here>)

line with the equivalent
`<command here>`

backticks version.  Any idea which plugin did this?  Also, how do I disable/remove one of these plugins that is installed in the Lazy starter collection?
I see the following on my system:
$ cat ~/.config/nvim/lazy-lock.json
{
"LazyVim": { "branch": "main", "commit": "d7c7548e09af1d26db57f10be3c77a58f010b1d5" },
"bufferline.nvim": { "branch": "main", "commit": "99337f63f0a3c3ab9519f3d1da7618ca4f91cffe" },
"catppuccin": { "branch": "main", "commit": "cc8e290d4c0d572171243087f8541e49be2c8764" },
"cmp-buffer": { "branch": "main", "commit": "3022dbc9166796b644a841a02de8dd1cc1d311fa" },
"cmp-nvim-lsp": { "branch": "main", "commit": "39e2eda76828d88b773cc27a3f61d2ad782c922d" },
"cmp-path": { "branch": "main", "commit": "91ff86cd9c29299a64f968ebb45846c485725f23" },
"conform.nvim": { "branch": "master", "commit": "cf562dd160c27a7fc5342dfce7e1227746dd3aaa" },
"copilot.vim": { "branch": "release", "commit": "1dcaf72099b436b5832d6117d9cd7a4a098a8d77" },
"dashboard-nvim": { "branch": "master", "commit": "5346d023afc4bfc7ff63d05c70bcdb0784bb657a" },
"dressing.nvim": { "branch": "master", "commit": "e3714c8049b2243e792492c4149e4cc395c68eb9" },
"flash.nvim": { "branch": "main", "commit": "43f67935d388fbb540f8b40e8cbfd80de54f978a" },
"friendly-snippets": { "branch": "main", "commit": "700c4a25caacbb4648c9a27972c2fe203948e0c2" },
"gitsigns.nvim": { "branch": "main", "commit": "4a143f13e122ab91abdc88f89eefbe70a4858a56" },
"indent-blankline.nvim": { "branch": "master", "commit": "d98f537c3492e87b6dc6c2e3f66ac517528f406f" },
"lazy.nvim": { "branch": "main", "commit": "fafe1f7c640aed75e70a10e6649612cd96f39149" },
"lazydev.nvim": { "branch": "main", "commit": "7cbb524c85f87017df9c1ea2377a1d840ad8ed51" },
"lualine.nvim": { "branch": "master", "commit": "0a5a66803c7407767b799067986b4dc3036e1983" },
"luvit-meta": { "branch": "main", "commit": "ce76f6f6cdc9201523a5875a4471dcfe0186eb60" },
"mason-lspconfig.nvim": { "branch": "main", "commit": "8db12610bcb7ce67013cfdfaba4dd47a23c6e851" },
"mason.nvim": { "branch": "main", "commit": "0950b15060067f752fde13a779a994f59516ce3d" },
"mini.ai": { "branch": "main", "commit": "a7e90f110e6274262616311b93cef12cd2667a2d" },
"mini.pairs": { "branch": "main", "commit": "40261dfcec7623cd57be3c3beb50fa73f2650cdf" },
"neo-tree.nvim": { "branch": "v3.x", "commit": "29f7c215332ba95e470811c380ddbce2cebe2af4" },
"noice.nvim": { "branch": "main", "commit": "e5cb20c6e14305d24025ecb77d7d4dd9d61f1a64" },
"nui.nvim": { "branch": "main", "commit": "322978c734866996274467de084a95e4f9b5e0b1" },
"nvim-cmp": { "branch": "main", "commit": "a110e12d0b58eefcf5b771f533fc2cf3050680ac" },
"nvim-lint": { "branch": "master", "commit": "941fa1220a61797a51f3af9ec6b7d74c8c7367ce" },
"nvim-lspconfig": { "branch": "master", "commit": "4d38bece98300e3e5cd24a9aa0d0ebfea4951c16" },
"nvim-notify": { "branch": "master", "commit": "d333b6f167900f6d9d42a59005d82919830626bf" },
"nvim-snippets": { "branch": "main", "commit": "5c978b3ba0c504dc9f94ca93d17029f26064d229" },
"nvim-spectre": { "branch": "master", "commit": "ec67d4b5370094b923dfcf6b09b39142f2964861" },
"nvim-treesitter": { "branch": "master", "commit": "3b5704440f88ecc98fb5afb5378b95acd4b2fa7f" },
"nvim-treesitter-textobjects": { "branch": "master", "commit": "34867c69838078df7d6919b130c0541c0b400c47" },
"nvim-ts-autotag": { "branch": "main", "commit": "6eb4120a1aadef07ac312f1c4bc6456712220007" },
"nvim-web-devicons": { "branch": "master", "commit": "c0cfc1738361b5da1cd0a962dd6f774cc444f856" },
"persistence.nvim": { "branch": "main", "commit": "5fe077056c821aab41f87650bd6e1c48cd7dd047" },
"plenary.nvim": { "branch": "master", "commit": "a3e3bc82a3f95c5ed0d7201546d5d2c19b20d683" },
"telescope-fzf-native.nvim": { "branch": "main", "commit": "9ef21b2e6bb6ebeaf349a0781745549bbb870d27" },
"telescope.nvim": { "branch": "master", "commit": "f12b15e1b3a33524eb06a1ae7bc852fb1fd92197" },
"todo-comments.nvim": { "branch": "main", "commit": "5c01a8de1a187f090e485d88d99a0c11569e9a12" },
"tokyonight.nvim": { "branch": "main", "commit": "719713b0515c56fcb66ed2c1acd385d3e1de7895" },
"trouble.nvim": { "branch": "main", "commit": "4d0f0454ae2a246ec3e0ff541a347164dac23b7b" },
"ts-comments.nvim": { "branch": "main", "commit": "c075b4ee00f6e111b44bf99a8cfd5a4cfce9258a" },
"which-key.nvim": { "branch": "main", "commit": "0099511294f16b81c696004fa6a403b0ae61f7a0" }
}

From just skimming this list, I have a suspicion that conform.nvim may be the culprit.  But, I'm new to NeoVim and to Lazy, and I don't know how to disable/remove any of these plugins.  So I cannot experiment.

Did you read https://www.lazyvim.org/configuration/plugins already?

@mkrieger1 I did, but I couldn't figure out how to disable the plugins that were added by the starter pack.  Having said that, I will take another careful look at this, and try again.
